# load balancer - web app AZURE

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've deployed my php app on azure (web app MS + SQL).
I'd like to do a load balancer for education purpose and I have no idea how to do it, cause every tutorial is for VM's or app sevice enviroment.
how could i do load balancer with app service or should I deploy my project on virtual machine?

Answer (score 2):

Azure App Service has a built in load balancer. You can add more nodes by scaling out.

[image: Azure Web App Scale Out]

Reference Article [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/scale-a-web-app-using-azure-scale-out/)

Comment: I'm using free plan and there isn't any autoscale option. And I'd like to do it on my own for education purpose like doing it with VMs, when you have to configure 'few things'

Comment: Web apps have load balancing built in. All you do is set the number of instances you want to run. If you are on the lower tiered app plans you will not have that capability.